# Does Cisco ASA support encrypted logging

Tags: cisco-asa, logging

**Background**
I am approaching this from a SIEM or Log Collection point of view. Our corporation is thinking about making encrypted logging mandatory

**Question**
Cisco ASA default appears to me to be send logs via syslog on udp/514. Is this the only option or can we enable more secure logging such as syslog over tls?

**Reference**
Generic logging reference
https://sflanders.net/2018/08/22/syslog-and-what-protocol-to-send-events-over/

Thanks, J

Comment: Not in any version I'm aware of. The newer NGFW/FTD stuff might, but I've never looked at it. There's always IPSec to your syslog server. :-)

Comment: Thanks for posting Ricky. And intersting option to ipsec to syslog server. Out of band someone pointed me towards a YouTube video showing Secure TLS syslog - so thanks to "October Leaf"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This YouTube tutorial by October Leaf describes how to secure syslog traffic using certificates between a Cisco asa and syslog server.

Link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QTg8kslk20&t=1216s

Channel:
https://www.youtube.com/@octoberleaf585

So today I learned this can be done. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well look at that. "secure" was added in 8.0(2) apparently (which means all the way back to the PIX!) Cisco, of course, provides useless documentation for the feature.

Comment: Yes, the Borg does not help itself. I asked 2 CCIE's and they both said secure Syslog is not supported. The 3rd one pointed me to the video above. Credit to the YouTuber octoberleaf585

Comment: After a lot of digging, I did find [ https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/asr9000/software/asr9k-r7-3/system-security/configuration/guide/b-system-security-cg-asr9000-73x/implementing-secure-logging.pdf ] FOR AN ASR9k. And even that's not the complete story.

Comment: Apparently SSL/TLS was added to Rsyslog around 2008, but it's been a damned well hidden secret. Nobody's talking about it. 'tho I can find many references to people using ipsec as I suggested.